# Editing comments with inline code removes code markers and triples the text

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, code-formatting

Sorry for the long title, but I think it aptly describes the problem.

For an example, on [this answer on the PPCG meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13306/69054), I commented the text:

> I made a bunch of edits, feel free to roll back any changes you dislike. For the case of `100,000`, should you return `.1M`, `0.1M`, or `100K`?

All the numbers are delimited by backticks because I wanted to format them with sans-serif font. This is more commonly done for code in comments.

When I go to edit the comment, I get this text:

> I made a bunch of edits, feel free to roll back any changes you dislike. For the case of 100,000100,000100,000, should you return .1M.1M.1M, 0.1M0.1M0.1M, or 100K100K100K?

Even if I resubmit the comment without making any additional edits myself, this new version is what appears in the comment.

I apologize if this is a dupe, but I've searched through as many other questions about editing comments with inline code that I could find and haven't found a report of this particular bug.

Update: I wrote the following comment on this post:

> I am on desktop, running Chrome on Linux. Is it possible this is only happening on PPCG? I wonder `if I can reproduce it here`

When I edited it, I got:

> I am on desktop, running Chrome on Linux. Is it possible this is only happening on PPCG? I wonder ifIcanre∏uceithereifIcanre∏uceithereif I can reproduce it here

Update 2: This doesn't seem to occur in Firefox on Linux, and other users aren't able to replicate the problem, so it *might* be some sort of script running in my Chrome browser.

Update 3: I have managed to solve the issue for myself. If the question no longer belongs on here due to the solution, I am happy to delete it.

Comment: Are on mobile or desktop? I can't reproduce it on the desktop version

Comment: I am on desktop, running Chrome on Linux. It doesn't seem to be a PPCG-specific issue as it is happening here as well

Comment: I have Windows 10 and Chrome. Are you running any scripts that can affect text? If so, turn them off then test

Comment: This doesn't appear to happen in Firefox on Linux, so it might be a script or plugin in my Chrome browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved for me by disabling the [MathJax for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathjax-for-chrome/elbbpgnifnallkilnkofjcgjeallfcfa?hl=en-GB) plugin I had installed. It didn't even work for me, I guess I should have read the [reviews](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathjax-for-chrome/elbbpgnifnallkilnkofjcgjeallfcfa/reviews?hl=en-GB)...